# How do gang claims interact with the alcoholics group therapy program?

Tags: prison-architect

With the newly arrived version Alpha 35, gangs can claim yards and common rooms, which means that members of other gangs can no longer use them without getting attacked and non-gang prisoners need to pay when they use it.

How does this feature interact with the alcoholics group therapy program? This program is held by the psychologist in a commons room. What happens when that room is claimed by a gang?

Will members of other gangs be able to attend safely? Will non-gang prisoners have to pay to attend? Will my psychologist be safe?

Answer (score 2):

While in reality, none of your staff (if they interact with prisoners) are *ever* safe, the psychologist is only in any real danger if there's a gang fight in the common room at the time of the class. I'm not exactly sure if a prisoner's gang status is put on hold during a class session, but a controlling gang member may stop an opposing gang member from ever entering the room in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that giving gang members the ability to access a common room during their free time while an AA session is taking place there will increase the risk of your psychologist dying.

I would say it is not such a big deal, as the psychologist is not more expensive than any of the other civilian staff members that come into contact with prisoners (janitors, cooks if you use multiple 'eat' times).

Trying to do so in my maximum security prison may have gotten a psychologist or two killed, but it may require more experimentation to be 'sure'; the gang leader was engaging in a perpetual killing-punishment cycle due to his reputation combo, upsetting all the prisoners when in the 'punishment' phase, which may have been the cause for some of the dead psychologists there too. (The guy has 100 kills and counting...)

Answer (score -1):

With my understanding of the gangs mechanic, only prisoners and guards (normal, armed, dog handlers) are taken into consideration. So I think that only prisoners in the gang that claimed the common room would be able to attend, but the psychiatrist shouldn't be in any more danger than if the room was neutral.

Comment: Did you actually witness this in the game?

Comment: No, I'm just going by what I saw and heard in the Alpha 35 video.